# ¿Qué significa "me coloqué" en España?

Tags: significado, españa, coloquialismos

¿Qué significa "me coloqué" en España?

Estaba leyendo [una noticia](http://www.abc.es/sociedad/abci-no-tenia-300-euros-para-cocaina-y-coloque-solo-20-201610302134_noticia.html) y un joven decía:

> No tenía para cocaína y **me coloqué** por 20.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Te he dejado una respuesta, pero lo normal es que una pregunta muestre algo de trabajo previo. Es decir, qué crees que significa, dónde has buscado información sobre el término antes de preguntar, etc. Si no sabes por dónde empezar, tenemos un post muy bueno que te puede ayudar: [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2514/12637). ¡Esperamos que te diviertas y aprendas mucho!

Answer (score 1):

> **[colocar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9p46KCK)**
>
> Del lat. *collocāre*.
>
> 5. tr. coloq. Dicho del alcohol o de una droga: Causar un estado eufórico a alguien.
> 6. prnl. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Ponerse bajo los efectos del alcohol o de una droga.

La versión transitiva se aplicaría a la sustancia en sí: "esto te coloca", y la versión pronominal a la persona: "Fulano se colocó".

También tienes "colocón" como sustantivo:

> **[colocón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9pB012L)**
>
> 1. m. coloq. Efecto intenso de colocarse (‖ ponerse bajo los efectos del alcohol o de una droga).

Comment: Leyendo la noticia de donde parece que sale la frase, parece que se refiere a colocarse con heroína como sustitutivo a hacerlo con cocaína.

Comment: @fedorqui posiblemente, pero el uso de "colocarse" sigue siendo el mismo que recoge el diccionario.

Comment: Sí, es una palabra muy coloquial que se usa para describir un estado de embriaguez causado por cualquier droga, legal o ilegal, sobre todo entre las personas relativamente jóvenes. Yo tengo treinta y ocho y a veces lo sigo usando hasta para el tabaco, por ejemplo si no fumo en mucho tiempo, por trabajo o un transporte largo(tren, avión), cuando vuelves a fumar te mareas un poco y ahí va el "¡vaya colocón!". Costumbres de cuando uno era más joven ;)

Comment: Sí. Supongo que el OP no cogió todo el contexto de la frase.

Comment: @fedorqui ya por curiosidad, ¿qué significa "OP"?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo de [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/209901): _The person who wrote the question. Alternatively (rarely) OP can be used to refer to the Original Post (question) itself._. El que hizo la pregunta, vaya.